# mac mouse event delta value is not accurate

Tags: objective-c, macos

On Mac OSX, I tried 2 ways to get the deltaX and deltaY on mouse moved event:

1. `deltaX`/`deltaY` of `NSEvent`
2. `kCGMouseEventDeltaX`/`kCGMouseEventDeltaY` of `CGEventRef`

But most times, the returned value is (0,0) or (aValue, 0) or (0, aValue), not a very accurate value.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not on my dev machine to test this, but I can reference the source code we use for this kind of problem

First, it's weird that `deltaX` and `deltaY` don't work for you?
One thing I would try is
`NSLog(@"POINT: %@", NSStringFromPoint([event locationInWindow]);`
to see if the location of the event is actually moving around, without using breakpoints.  If you are testing the delta with breakpoints, it's possible that `mouseMoved` fires so frequently that you don't see a large delta

But anyways, one thing I noticed is that in our app, we actually don't use `deltaX/deltaY` either.  Maybe because the developer back in the day came across the same issue as you?  But still weird IMO.  I want to test this more when I get back home this weekend

We actually have a `NSPoint` property called `lastPoint`, and every time the mouse moves, the last thing we do is store the `locationInWindow` into that property.  Then **first** thing we do is compare the `lastPoint` with the current `locationInWindow`.

But honestly this seems like a bad solution, I'm really not sure why we don't just use `deltaX` or `deltaY`.  I would recommend doing more debugging (with `NSLogs`) to figure out what could be going wrong with using those properties

Comment: yes, I am also considering a property storing the last mouse location :)

Comment: try it out!  report back.  If I remember to, I'll investigate later too